# Is there a way to get feedback on the size of different files used in a Blender project?

Tags: materials, blend-files

I teach Blender in an art class and students have often difficulties knowing why their file is getting so big, in terms of project file size.

It's often because they download materials with a lot of textures (eg. from BlenderKit).

I was wondering if there is a native way (or using a plugin) to get feedback in a project and know what makes it big.

Comment: It sounds as if File > External Data > Automatically Pack Resources may be checked on your students' copies of Blender. This will massively inflate the project file size as all the textures will be included within the Blend file. However the path to the location of their texture files will always have to remain the same if that option is unchecked so this may not be convenient for your use in this case.

Comment: Hello - I know that, but what i'm wondering is if there is a way to have an idea of the size of each item (in this case, materials / textures) so they could inspect their project..

Comment: Not to my knowledge

Answer (score 2):

You can inspect and check the file size of all the images or textures that have been packed into the blend file via *File > External Data > Automatically Pack Resources* using the following script. First make sure your console is open by going to menu *Window > Toggle System Console* and execute the script.

[image]

```
import bpy
import os

TOTAL_FILE_SIZE = 0

for img in bpy.data.images:
    if not img.packed_file:
        continue
    filepath = bpy.path.abspath(img.filepath)
    filepath = os.path.normpath(filepath)
    size = os.path.getsize(filepath) / 1024 / 1024
    TOTAL_FILE_SIZE += size
    print(img.name, size, "MB")

print("TOTAL FILE SIZE:", TOTAL_FILE_SIZE, "MB")
```

Sometimes you have unused images or textures in your file that contribute to the bloating. In this case you can remove them by going to menu *File > Clean Up*.

Comment: Very useful. It seems the size is also already stored in `img.packed_file.size`

Comment: nice! thanks for the info, thats good to know

Comment: Seems interesting and would be a wonderful addon to make :)  But here on Linux, I don't have no *Window > Toggle System Console *, cannot find how to run it.

Comment: on linux you can just open a terminal and run blender with command `blender` and you will immediately see the output in that same terminal for whatever you print out in your blender python scripts.